# Launching anaconda spyder gui in cygwin

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, cluster-computing, anaconda

I am connecting my windows 7 computer to a linux based cluster using cygwin.  Within a specific node in the cluster I want to launch the anaconda spyder gui.

to launch spyder you simply type:

`spyder` into cygwin

but that returns:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried:

```
QTA_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen spyder
```

but that returns:

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /home/spotter/anaconda2/lib/fonts - is Qt installed correctly?
```

I installed qt4 dev-tools but it didn't change anything

EDIT:

I installed xinit and xorg and now I try this:

before logging in with ssh i run:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

then I login using ssh:

```
ssh -Y -X usrname@machine
```

and now when I try to use `spyder` I get:

```
connect localhost port 6000: Connection refused
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you are running Cygwin on your local Windows machine, logging into a remote server with `ssh`, and running `spyder` from that machine with the intent of having it show up on your local screen.  Now that you have `startx` working, you are close to a solution.

Between steps 5 and 6, you need to run the `export DISPLAY` command *on the remote machine* and set it to the name of your local computer.  You will need to know your hostname for this.  The steps will look like this:

```
 startx
 ssh -Y -X username@machine
 export DISPLAY=win-machine-name:0.0
 spyder
```

The last two commands are executed on the remote machine.  I just made up the `win-machine-name`.  In its place, you will put the IP address or machine name of your windows machine.  That is how you tell set the `DISPLAY` environment variable on the remote machine, so `X` clients know where to send the graphics commands.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me what I did was:

1. Install packages associated with startx
2. Change the sshd_config file to allow X11 forwarding
3. `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`
4. `startx`
5. login with `ssh -Y -X username@machine`
6. `spyder`